# XPath Assertion Expression for checking presence of elements in nested tree

Tags: xml, xpath, nested, axis, assertion

I am struggling with writing the correct Xpath assertion statement to test for the presence of the  element.

I need to add an assertion to the xml schema so that:

1. Every `<instruction>` must have a `<stroke>` or its parent `<repetition>` has a `<stroke>`. They cannot both have `<stroke>` and they cannot both have not `<stroke>` (XOR).
2. An `<instruction>` directly under `<program>` must have a `<stroke>` since it cannot have a parent `<repetition>`.
3. If a `<repetition>` has a `<stroke>` element, then none of its descendants can have a `<stroke>`. This includes children of all types.
4. If a `<repetition>` has no `<stroke>` element, then all its `<instructions>` children must have a `<stroke>`.
5. If a `<repetition>` has no `<stroke>`, then its `<repetition>` children can also have no `<stroke>` (XOR).

I created a series of test scenarios and commented if the case is valid or not. Any help with sorting through this problem would be appreciated. I struggle with the presence of the `<stroke>`? element in uncles.

I realise that an XOR has to be written out:

```
<xs:assert test="stroke and not(descendant::stroke) or descendant::stroke and not(stroke)"/>
```

This would solve constraint 3, but unfortunately descendant also takes its direct child `<stroke>` into account. It should only look for children of the type `<repetition>` and `<instruction>`.

Here is the test scenarios:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<program xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 


<!-- case 1: valid -->
<instruction>
    <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
    <stroke>
        <standardStroke>backstroke</standardStroke>
    </stroke>
</instruction>

<!-- case 2: invalid -->
<instruction>
    <lengthAsDistance>200</lengthAsDistance>
</instruction>

<!-- case 3: valid -->
<instruction>
    <repetition>
        <repetitionCount>3</repetitionCount>
        <stroke>
            <standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke>
        </stroke>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
        </instruction>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>200</lengthAsDistance>
        </instruction>            
    </repetition>
</instruction>

<!-- case 4: invalid -->
<instruction>
    <repetition>
        <repetitionCount>3</repetitionCount>
        <stroke>
            <standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke>
        </stroke>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
            <stroke>
                <standardStroke>backstroke</standardStroke>
            </stroke>
        </instruction>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>200</lengthAsDistance>
        </instruction>            
    </repetition>
</instruction>

<!-- case 5: valid -->
<instruction>
    <repetition>
        <repetitionCount>3</repetitionCount>
        <stroke>
            <standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke>
        </stroke>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
        </instruction>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>200</lengthAsDistance>
        </instruction>
        <instruction>
            <repetition>
                <repetitionCount>4</repetitionCount>
                <instruction>
                    <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
                </instruction>
            </repetition>
        </instruction>
    </repetition>
</instruction>


<!-- case 6: invalid -->
<instruction>
    <repetition>
        <repetitionCount>3</repetitionCount>
        <stroke>
            <standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke>
        </stroke>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
        </instruction>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>200</lengthAsDistance>
        </instruction>
        <instruction>
            <repetition>
                <repetitionCount>4</repetitionCount>
                <stroke>
                    <standardStroke>backstroke</standardStroke>
                </stroke>
                <instruction>
                    <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
                </instruction>
            </repetition>
        </instruction>
    </repetition>
</instruction>

<!-- case 7: invalid -->
<instruction>
    <repetition>
        <repetitionCount>3</repetitionCount>
        <stroke>
            <standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke>
        </stroke>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
        </instruction>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>200</lengthAsDistance>
        </instruction>
        <instruction>
            <repetition>
                <repetitionCount>4</repetitionCount>
                <instruction>
                    <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
                    <stroke>
                        <standardStroke>backstroke</standardStroke>
                    </stroke>
                </instruction>
            </repetition>
        </instruction>
    </repetition>
</instruction>


<!-- case 8: valid -->
<instruction>
    <repetition>
        <repetitionCount>3</repetitionCount>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
            <stroke>
                <standardStroke>backstroke</standardStroke>
            </stroke>
        </instruction>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>200</lengthAsDistance>
            <stroke>
                <standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke>
            </stroke>
        </instruction>            
    </repetition>
</instruction>

<!-- case 9: invalid -->
<instruction>
    <repetition>
        <repetitionCount>3</repetitionCount>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
            <stroke>
                <standardStroke>backstroke</standardStroke>
            </stroke>
        </instruction>
        <instruction>
            <lengthAsDistance>200</lengthAsDistance>
        </instruction>            
    </repetition>
</instruction>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude child `stroke` elements from other descendant `stroke` elements by starting your `descendant` XPath from the child elements of the context element, e.g.

```xml
stroke and not(*/descendant::stroke) or */descendant::stroke and not(stroke)
```

Instead of:

```xml
stroke and not(descendant::stroke) or descendant::stroke and not(stroke)
```

Comment: I added this to the schema definition of `<repetition>` and case 1 and 2 were validated correctly. Already for case 3 the validation was incorrect. The problem could be the nesting of the `<instruction>` elements. The second level of instructions are identified as invalid, possibly because they do not themselves have a `<stroke>`  as a child or descendants. They do not need it, because their parent `<repetition>` already has a `<stroke>` element.

Comment: I am sorry, slight correction. I had added your xpath statement to the `<instruction>` definition.

Comment: Can you list your other assertions, please? You only presented one, so it was the only one I commented on.

Comment: I have not been able to write the assertions. All my attempts failed to clear all the test scenarios. The xml schema with all my attempts commented out is available here: https://github.com/bartneck/swiML/blob/main/swiML.xsd

Comment: I think in pseudo code a solution could be: every `<instruction>` must have a `<stroke>` unless one of its `<repetition>` ancestors has a `<stroke>` (XOR). If the parent of a `<instruction>` is root, then it must have a `<stroke>` element since it cannot have a `<repetition>` element as an ancestor.

Comment: When you say "every instruction must have a stroke ..." you mean "it must have a stroke as a descendant"?

Comment: In the XML above you notice that the `<instruction>` element can have a child `<stroke>' element. `<instruction>` can also have a `<repetition>` child, which in turn can have a `<stroke>` child. The XML is setup so that the `<instruction>` and `<repetition>` can be nested at an unlimited depth.